# Order of columns(variables) in proc append

Tags: sas, append

I am fairly new to SAS.

I wanted to append two datasets **Dataset1** and **Dataset2**

The order of columns in **Dataset1** is `A B C`

The order of columns in **Dataset2** is  `b A c`

**Note the case of the column names(upper case and lower case)**

So if I do

```
PROC APPEND BASE=Dataset1 DATA=Dataset2 FORCE;
```

RUN;

Will the appending happend in a desired way :

```
A should append to A

B should append to b

C should append to c
```

Comment: Case doesn't matter so short answer, yes. Also note that the resulting dataset will retain the properties of the `BASE` dataset.

Comment: The appending will happen even if the type of two columns in different ?

Comment: If the columns are different data types then the dataset being appended will have its values set to missing.

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Comment: @Tom It got merged and there were too many warnings saying the type in base is different from type in data.So was wondering if it has any negative effects on appending(as in loss of rows or any undesirable thing)

Comment: The case of the names doesn't matter, but the variables do need to be compatible. And if you are trying to append strings that are longer than what the base dataset can hold then their values will be truncated.

Comment: Do the variables/columns need to be in same order in both the dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither case nor position matter for columns.

Columns are identified by their names, not their position.

Examples can help demonstrate this; try running the following one step at a time; read the comments, check the log and examine the data sets:

```
/* creates data set have1 with columns a (char), b (numeric) then c (numeric) */
data have1;
   length a $ 1;

   input a b c;

   datalines;
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
;

/* creates data set have2 with columns b (char), a (numeric) then c (numeric) */
data have2;
   length b $ 1;

   input a b c;

   datalines;
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
;

/* attempts append, but as a & b have different types, missing values result */
proc append base = have1
            data = have2
            force
            ;
run;

/* creates data set have3 with columns a (char), b (numeric) then c (numeric) */
data have3;
   length a $ 1;

   input a b c;

   datalines;
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
;

/* creates data set have4 with columns b (numeric), a (char) then c (numeric) */
data have4;
   length b   8;
   length a $ 1;

   input a b c;

   datalines;
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
;

/* Appends successfully as variable types are the same even though order is different. */
/* Columns are identified by their names, not their position.                          */
proc append base = have3
            data = have4
            force
            ;
run;
```

**EDIT:** In answer to the question in the comment:

> Having same type but different format.Example `num` type but `DATE9.`
>   format and other column has `num` type but `ddmmyy` format will this
>   cause any problem ?

The format of a variable affects the way it is displayed, the underlying data remains unchanged, so appending one numeric column with another is possible, the only difference would be is that the appended data will be in the same format as the base data, as noted by @J_Lard in the first comment to your question.

Again, an example might help to demonstrate this:

```
/* creates data set have5 with columns a (numeric, formst date9.) and text */
data have5;
   format a date9.;

   input text $char10.;

   a = input(text,ddmmyy10.);

   datalines;
31/07/2018
;

/* creates data set have6 with columns a (numeric, formst ddmmyy.) and text */
data have6;
   format a ddmmyy.;

   input text $char10.;

   a = input(text,ddmmyy10.);

   datalines;
31/07/2018
;

/* appends, but see warning in log about format */
proc append base = have5
            data = have6
            force
            ;
run;
```

Hopefully you can see the approach to take if you have more questions you need answering (create test data then append / process). If you still have problems then I would suggest asking a new question, with a link to this one, if relevant, supplying test data steps for others to run and the code you've tried with any log messages.

Comment: Having same type but different format.Example `num` type but `DATE9.`  format and other column has `num` type but `ddmmyy` format will this cause any problem ?

Comment: See relevant "EDIT" in answer.